# Adding role with UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build simple method (just to test how it works), which will grant me (current user) a new role (i have only 1 role for now, so i can get it by simple query)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var role = db.AspNetRoles.First();
        manager.AddToRole(id, role.Name);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I am getting this error: `The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.` 
on `manager.AddToRole(id, role.Name);` line. I am novice to ASP.NET so i don't know much about its infrastructure, however this code was mentioned a lot of times (here, on stack) in questions about user registration.

By the way, as my goal, i have to implement role system to project with database-first migration system, will this `manager.AddToRole(id, role.Name);` code add records in my DB?

Comment: What is `HRMEntities` and what does it inherit from?

Comment: You didn't by any chance rename your ApplicationUser table to something custom, did you? Also, like what DavidG is alluding to, are you sure your HRMEntities DB context is inheriting from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> ?

Comment: Sry, haven't fixed it  is a name of my connection string. Changed it to `MyDbContext`.

Comment: @Overhed, as far as i understand it has to be created automatically in my db, however i cant find it, i can see only AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetRoles, AspNetUsers. All of them are empty except AspNetUsers(populated with users, that data used to login) and AspNetRoles (is populated with 1 test role). Can you tell, what do i have to create\seed\rename?

Comment: Is `ApplicationUser` an EF entity?

Comment: I've added an portion of a method that adds a new user and assigns a role. However, the approach would be similar for adding an existing user to a role. Just supply the user.Id once you've instantiated a UserManager.

Comment: The AddToRole code would depend on the type of identity or membership system you are using in your db and the type of db as well.

Comment: @rainbowShiningUnicorn The ApplicationUser entity maps to the AspNetUsers table. You should be fine there as long as your MyDBContext class definition looks something like: public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Answer (score 0):

Below is a stub (incomplete), that shows adding a newly created user to a role:

```
            DbContext context = db;
            IdentityResult ir;
            var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
                new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            ApplicationUser au = new ApplicationUser();
            au = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == uname);

            if (au == null)
            {
                // add the user
                var user = new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    UserName = TrustNoOne("name", uname),
                    Email = TrustNoOne("email", uemail),
                    ProperUserName = TrustNoOne("propername", upropname)
                };

                // create a password for the user
                ir = um.Create(user, upass);

                // assign the user to a role
                if (User.IsInRole(urole) != true)
                {
                    ir = um.AddToRole(user.Id, urole);
                }
            }
```

Please note, uname, uemail, upropname, upass, and urole are parameters passed to the method where this code lives. Also, you can ignore the TrustNoOne bit (it's just something I use).